# Object Reference Not Set To An Instance on GeoLocation Interface

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, interface, xamarin.android, geolocation

I am facing problem when implementing Interface class in Xamarin.Android. I want to pass `IHery.Message()` value from Xamarin.Android project to Xamarin.Forms interface.

Here's in my Form App (IHery.cs):

```
public interface IHery
{
    Task<string> Message(string text);
}
```

And this is how I called it in MainPage.cs:

```
Task<string> xx = DependencyService.Get<IHery>().Message("Hi ");
Content = new Label{ Text = xx.GetAwaiter().GetResult() };
```

Here's how I implement in Xamarin.Android (T2S.cs):

```
async Task<string> IHery.Message(string text)
{
      var pos = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
      var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(pos);

      return location.Latitude.ToString() + @"," + location.Longitude.ToString();
}
```

In Android manifest.xml I have enable the `AccessCoarseLocation` and `AccessFineLocation` and I have add these code :

```
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.gps", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.network", Required = false)]
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(T2S))]
```

at the top of my T2S.cs in Xamarin.Android.

At the MainActivity.cs in Xamarin.Android, I have added these line:

```
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

and this:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults); base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

When I run, the error return error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on file MainPage.cs at line `Task<string> location = DependencyService.Get<...`.

Comment: Is `DependencyService` equal to `null`?

Comment: the first thing you need to do is isolate which specific line is causing the exception - most likely its "DependencyService.Get<IHery>()".  Did you decorate your IHery implementation with "[assembly: Dependency()]" attribute?  Finally, there is a Forms GeoLocation plugin that does most of this work for you.

Comment: @mywills yes it return null.

Comment: @Jason, I tried to do something else, so I just put a sample here. That's why I am not using the plugin.